# Kapacitor wiith HBase

Tags: hbase, alert, kapacitor

I'm trying to build an alerting system over Hbase where i do store my time series , my question is are they any way to plug kapacitor to hbase ? since I have read that kapacitor may not require influxdb to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there currently isn't a way to use Kapacitor with HBase. If this functionality is particularly important to you, I'd recommend opening up a [feature request on Kapacitor](https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/issues/new) detailing your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use OpenTSDB, which is storing data in HBase?

In that case you can send data to InfluxDB, which supports OpenTSDB format. Kapacitor may then query InfluxDB or get real-time data stream.

I think it should be easy to reuse OpenTSDB endpoint from InfluxDB codebase and allow Kapacitor accept data in OpenTSDB format - for stream-based alerting. (May request on Kapacitor github).

If you want just batch processing, you may create a translater service in the middle to convert queries from Kapacitor into OpenTSDB format.

Although I would generally recommend to switch to InfluxDB, because its ingestion rates are far superior than those of OpenTSDB.